# Durandal Composition

Tags: composition, durandal

```
<div>
<div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/header'"></div>
</div>
```

I am using Durandal Composition as shown in the above lines of code. Is it possible to pass some additional parameters to my viewmodel while using composition ? For example, the 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/system' parameters which are normally passed in the main.js file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass activationData like:

```
compose: {
                                model:'yourModel',
                                view: 'yourView',
                                activationData:  [param1, param2],
                                activate: true }
```

Comment: How can we access the passed parameter in activate method ?

Comment: like {activate: function(param1, param2){ console.log([param1,param2])}}

Comment: Yes, I did try this before but I keep getting the value as undefined in the activate function even when I try to pass a constant value like 10.

Comment: Have you update to the newest version of durandal ? 2.0.1 ? Maybe ist an bug ?

Comment: @user2585299, you could post your viewmodel if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I have added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass an array as ActivationData.  But you can pass an array inside of a JavaScript object.  I seem to recall reading something about that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In durandal version 1.1, activationData is not passed while making a call to viewModel.activator().activateItem() within tryActivate method in composition.js. I passed it explicitly to get the value of activationData in the viewmodel as shown below:

```
function tryActivate(settings, successCallback) {
    if (shouldPerformActivation(settings)) {
        viewModel.activator().activateItem(settings.model).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                successCallback();
            }
        });
    } else {
        successCallback();
    }
}
```

Only viewmodel parameter was passed to activateItem as seen above. I also passed the activationData parameter from there as below:

```
viewModel.activator().activateItem(settings.model,settings.activationData).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                successCallback();
            }
        });
```